# Как установить windows 10 на второй жесткий диск, когда на первом стоит linux(Pop-Os LTS Nvidia)

Tags: linux, windows, grub, windowsinstaller

В заголовке в принципе всё расписано. Но есть еще один вопрос. В линухе второй жесткий диск смонтирован, то-есть сначала мне нужно его размонтировать, потом запускаться с загрузочной флешки? И нужно ли мне менять файловую систему второго диска? Просто я новичок в линуховской тематике, прошу, не судите строго

Comment: Зачем задавать совершенно базовые вопросы тут? Найдите по Google инструкцию, попробуйте, возвращайтесь, если не будет получаться.

Comment: Отсоединить винт с линуксом, установить винду, подключить диск обратно. Неужели не помогло?

Comment: В гугле пишут как ставить рядом, а если и есть инструкции на второй диск, то говорят, что нужно поставить сначала винду а потом линух. На днях попробую отсоединить диск и установить так. Позже отпишусь

Answer (score 1):

Установить Линукс на первый диск. Установить Винду на второй. Загрузится в Линукс с БИОС через Ф8 и терминале ввести sudo upgrade-grub. Грув найдет Винду и добавит в меню загрузки. При перезагрузке можно будет выбирать систему стрелочками или загрузка по умолчанию, при условии, что загрузка в БИОС с Линукс. Второй вариант выбирать загрузку с БИОС. Но Линукс все равно обнаружит Винду при очередном обновлении ядра.